# Node as block: Is there a module?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

Is there any module for Drupal 8 that will do same functionality as nodeblock does, or do we have to programmatically render it?

Answer (score 2):

NodeBlock has been replaced by [EntityBlock](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityblock) in Drupal 8.